# Decompress uploaded files using flask or javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

so in my website i got two interfaces the first is used to upload files and the second to run a python script that finds duplicated files and keep only one then sort them into folders for their respective extension. But now i'm only accepting .rar and .zip files and i want to extract them right after uploading and before using the python script.

So can someone tell me how to extract those files into a specific folder using either flask or js.

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the zipfile and rarfile module

If you do not have rarfile module, install it.

```
pip install rarfile
```

For example

```py
from flask import request
import zipfile
import rarfile 

@example.route('/upload',methods= ['POST'])
     file = request.files['file']
     
     saveFilePath = "saveFilePath"
     extractpath = "extractpath"

     file.save(saveFilePath)

     if file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() == 'zip':
          zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(saveFilePath)
          zip_ref.extractall(extractpath)
          zip_ref.close()
     else: # rar
          rar_ref = rarfile.RarFile(saveFilePath)
          rar_ref.extractall(extractpath)
          rar_ref.close()

     # put your logic below
     ......
     ......
```

Comment: i've done this but it doesn't seem to work for me , can you look into it pls
https://codepen.io/ya-hia/pen/vYxKGpN

Comment: What is the name of the file upload input?

Comment: it's 'fileUpload'

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Any error message? And stuck at?

Comment: i'm getting this : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\PFE Website\\static\\uploads'

Comment: It means the python program needs the write file permission. Do you use the linux system or mac os? You need to promote the permission for the python program.

Comment: i'm using windows 10

Comment: You could use administrator permission to run the python program.

Comment: okay i'll try that thanks a lot brother :D

Comment: Hi again , so i managed to get the zip to work but now i'm having this error with the rar : rarfile.RarCannotExec: Cannot find working tool ,
got any idea what does this mean??

Comment: Try to refer this https://programmerah.com/python-rarfile-unpack-rar-package-error-rarfile-rarcannotexec-cannot-find-working-tool-165/